# Math mode inside textcolor ruins line spacing

Tags: macros, line-spacing

To format my paragraphs, I use a macro I call `Def`:

`\newcommand{\Def}[2]{\noindent{\footnotesize\textcolor{darkgray}{\textit{#1} #2}}}`

This causes some problems when I try to use math mode inside the argument. In particular, whenever I put a `$$foo$$` inside the macro, I get issues with line spacing. This

```
%kodowanie znakow i jezyk 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{polski}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

%wieksze marginesy
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\newcommand{\Def}[2]{\noindent{\footnotesize\textcolor{darkgray}{\textit{#1} #2}}}
\newcommand{\Par}[2]{\noindent\textbf{#1} #2}
\newcommand{\mcal}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
\newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
\newcommand{\mbf}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}

\begin{document}

...

\Def{Zanurzenie w pierścień uniwersalny.}{Weźmy skończony podzbiór $\Sigma = \{\sigma_1, \ldots, \sigma_n\}$ zbioru $T$. Możemy określić iniekcję pierścienia $R[X_{\sigma_1}, \ldots, X_{\sigma_n}]$ w $R[\{X_t\}]$ w ten sposób, że wielomianowi $c = \sum_{r_1, \ldots, r_n} c_{r_1 \ldots r_n}X_{\sigma_1}^{r_1} \ldots X_{\sigma_n}^{r_n}$ przypisujemy funkcję $c$ określoną warunkami:
$$
c(r) = \begin{cases} c_{r_1 \ldots r_n} &  \:r(\sigma_i) = r_i \text{ dla wszystkich } \sigma_i \in \Sigma \text{ oraz } r(\sigma_i) = 0, \text{ gdy } t \notin \Sigma,\\
    0 & \text{ w przeciwnym przypadku.}
\end{cases}
$$
Tak określone przekształcenie jest homomorfizmem.  }
\\


\Def{Pierścienie ideałów głównych.}{Pierścień przemienny $R$ jest \textbf{pierścieniem ideałów głównych}, gdy każdy ideał $I \subset R$ jest postaci $Ra$, $a \in R$. Jeśli $R$ jest pierścieniem ideałów głownych, a $I$ jego ideałem, to $R/I$ również jest pierścieniem ideałów głównych.}
\\
...

\end{document}
```

compiles to this:

[image: kompilacja z pdf]

Bottom paragraph is for comparison. I would like line spacing to stay regular in the paragraph that comes before the definition inside `$$...$$`. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

```
\newcommand{\Def}[2]{\noindent{\footnotesize\textcolor{darkgray}{\textit{#1} #2}}}
```

This ends the scope of footnotesize before the paragraph ends, so the final paragraph (or final partial paragraph after a math display) will use the footnotesize font but the baselineskip and other paragraph settings from the surrounding context which will be `\normalsize`.

You need `\par` after `#2` (actually after `\textcolor`, as noted by @campa) to ensure the paragraph ends within the correct scope. (And then remove the `\\`  following the command.

Note that `$$  ... $$` is not LaTeX and should be `\[...\]`

If you really want the smaller font but the standard baseline then add `\normalbaselines` so

```
 \newcommand{\Def}[2]{\noindent{\footnotesize\normalbaselines
                            \textcolor{darkgray}{\textit{#1} #2}\par}}
```

Comment: Of course I agree with the diagnosis, but I've got rather the impression that the OP wants in fact the "wrong" (larger) spacing.

Comment: @campa well `\footnotesize\baselineskip=\normalbaselineskip` if you _really_ want that (I chose not to believe that is what the OP meant)

Comment: @campa see updated answer

Comment: Oh, you don't have to convince/humor me `;-)` BTW shouldn't the `\par` go outside the argument of `\textcolor`? I don't think it's `\long`.

Comment: @campa hmm I wonder who wrote the `\textcolor` command? (fixed:-)

Comment: To be honest I didn't know the larger spacing is wrong. I'm happy to switch to the correct solution.

Comment: @ElanMehl there are no right and wrong actually, this is design not mathematics, but normally larger fonts are set on a larger baseline and smaller ones set on a smaller. the class you are using specifies the baseline to use for each font size when setting up `\footnotesize`, `\large` and related commands.

Comment: @ElanMehl Please note that I had put the word "wrong" in scare quotes. I didn't mean that what you want is wrong (it's a legitimate request) but only that that what you considered strange was in fact the expected (from TeX's point of view) behaviour. I shouldn't have used the word "wrong", sorry.

Comment: @campa no worries! In any case, it's true that the definitions are more compact and legible when they're spaced more thinly.